# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code but when there's a problem and the console log this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

```
$(function () {
       var clicks = 0;
      setLike('<?php echo $notrepage ?>');
      FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
         if (getcookie('<? url_to_cookie($fbpage) ?>')) {
            setLike('<?php echo $autrepage;?>');
            var clicks = 1,
            cooo = <? url_to_cookie($autrepage) ?> ;
         } else if (clicks == 1) {
            setcookie(cooo, '1', 350);
            $("#inner-follow").remove();
            $("#likeplay").remove();
            document.getElementById("dsfsd").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("dsfsd").style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById("videos").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("videos").style.visibility = 'visible';
            getViedo();
         } else if (clicks = 0) {
            setLike('<?php echo $fbpage; ?>');
           var  clicks = 1,
            cooo = <? url_to_cookie($fbpage); ?> ;
         }

      });
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Read the generated source and you'll see the problem on the third to last line.

Comment: I think this must be escaped with '; so cooo = <? url_to_cookie($autrepage) ?> ; must be  cooo = '<? url_to_cookie($autrepage) ?>' ; don't define again the variable clicks, and the last elsse if must be ==0

Comment: it's work i missed "});" at the end for "$(function () {"

Comment: Ok, good; but take a look to the other issues

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must be mising either a `}` or `)` or both something like `})`

Comment: I confirmed this for myself by comparing between versions of the file to find which `}` I was mising.

Answer (score 4):

`SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` means that the file ended, while the parser expected that there was more. This is usually caused by a typo, or a missing ) or }. Count the amount of opening ( and { and count the amount of ) and }. If they are not the same, you should figure out where you forgot to close them.

Comment: Appreciate reason for closing this question, but this helped me with debugging!