# Laravel Blade Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input in Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

Within a view of Laravel, I generate a report and charge it using ajax. In the report I have three buttons, one of them is "Add".
Clicking on the "Add button does not redirect me to the route (viewAlarmasConfDestinatarios), in which I should show another form with fields that I must complete.

`{{route ()}}` does not work within ajax

ajax:

```
function fetch_data()
    {

        var trHTML ='';

                   $.ajax({
                  url: 'reporteAlarmasConfiguracion/',
                  type: "GET",
                  data : {"_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                  dataType: "json",
                  success:function(data) 
                  {
                      if(data)
                      {

                                console.log('ENTRE AL FETCH_DATA');

                                  $('#locationA > tbody').empty();

                                  $.each(data, function(key, value)
                                  {
                                   var product_id = value.pais +'-'+ value.servicio +'-'+ value.denominacion;

                                    var url = '{{ route("viewAlarmasConfDestinatarios.index", ":id") }}';

                                    url = url.replace(':id',product_id);


                                    console.log(url);
                                    if($.trim(value.vigente) == '1')
                                    {

                                      console.log('ACTIVO');
                                      value.vigente='<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="'+ value.pais +'-'+ value.servicio +'-'+ value.denominacion+'">Activa</button>' ;
                                    }  
                                    if($.trim(value.vigente) == '0')
                                    {
                                      value.vigente='<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="'+ value.pais +'-'+ value.servicio +'-'+ value.denominacion+'"> Desactivada</button>' ;
                                    }  
                                    if($.trim(value.pais) == '1')
                                    {
                                      value.pais='AR';
                                    } 
                                    if($.trim(value.pais) == '2')
                                    {
                                      value.pais='UY';
                                    }  
                                    if($.trim(value.pais) == '3')
                                    {
                                      value.pais='PY';
                                    }  
                                    var data = {
                                          "_token": $('#token').val()
                                      };
                                    var urlparm=value.pais +'-'+ value.servicio +'-'+ value.denominacion;
                                    console.log(urlparm);

                          trHTML += '<tr id="fila"><td>' + value.pais + '</td><td>' + value.servicio + '</td><td>' + value.denominacion + '</td><td>' + value.descripcion + '</td><td>' + value.vigente + '</td><td>' + '<button type="button"  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" id="'+ value.pais +'-'+ value.servicio +'-'+ value.denominacion+'"> Eliminar</button>&nbsp' + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" id="'+ value.pais +'-'+ value.servicio +'-'+ value.denominacion+'"> Modificar</button>' + '</td><td>' + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs info"" id="'+ value.pais +'-'+ value.servicio +'-'+ value.denominacion+'" onclick="'+url+'">Cargar</button>' + '</td></tr>';
                            });


                            $('#locationA').append(trHTML);
                          }

                 }



                }); 



    }
```

route:

```
Route::get('/AlarmaConfDestinatarios/{denominacion?}', 'alarmasController@viewAlarmasConfDestinatarios')->name('viewAlarmasConfDestinatarios.index');
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf5Ii.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134903/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `{{route()}}` within double inverted quotes like:

```
 var url = "{{ route('viewAlarmasConfDestinatarios.index', ':id') }}";
```

Comment: It worked as follows:
change <button to <a

and the variable was defined like this:
 var url = '{{URL :: route ("viewAlarmasConfDestinatarios.index", ": id")}}';

<a type = "button" class = "btn btn-info btn-xs info" "id =" '+ value.pais +' - '+ value.service +' - '+ value.denomination2 +' "href =" ' + url + '"> Load </a>'